# How do I check whether i have configured monetdb to use BWD?

Tags: mysql, database, monetdb

I am working on monetdb and trying to run bitwise decomposition in it.

I am able to rum the server and the client window, but how do I check whether the BWD is implemented in it?
I also need to check how many CPUs anf GPUs my monetdb uses. How can I check that?

Comment: have you come to know that  how to check how many CPUs anf GPUs my monetdb uses?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Hannes' answer, you can run the sql query

```
select * from bwdevices();
```

to see if you have the module installed and if it finds any usable OpenCL devices.

That being said, I can only hope and pray that you are using the BWD module only for research purposes and don't try to run it in a production system. It is nowhere near production ready and may take some significant effort to get running for your case. If you are interested in getting it running for your case, feel free to contact the author, i.e., me (holger), by email.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to Bitwise Decomposition, this is not part of the normal MonetDB distribution. The "bwd" branch can be checked out from our source control system at http://dev.monetdb.org/hg/MonetDB/ .